# Problema com procedure de validação

Tags: sql, validação, stored-procedures, oracle12c, erp

Estou criando uma procedure para validar se o campo desconto (%) recebe uma porcentagem menor do que zero  (valor negativo) ou maior do que 100%.

Porém ao executar aparece um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver. Busquei em vários locais e cada fala um motivo diferente e mesmo seguindo não consegui resolver.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

O erro é o seguinte:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MV_VALIDA_DESCONTO_NEGATIVO'

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTE."MV_VALIDA_DESCONTO_NEGATIVO" (

       P_NUNOTA  INT,
       P_SUCESSO OUT VARCHAR2,
       P_MENSAGEM OUT VARCHAR2     
) AS
  
       P_PERCDESC FLOAT ;
      
BEGIN  
           SELECT ITE.PERCDESC INTO P_PERCDESC FROM TGFITE ITE
           WHERE ITE.NUNOTA = P_NUNOTA;
      
       
    /* VERIFICA SE O CAMPO PERCENTUAL DE DESCONTO RECEBE VALOR NEGATIVO */
       IF (P_PERCDESC < 0) THEN 
        P_SUCESSO  := 'N';          
P_MENSAGEM := ' PERCENTUAL NÃO PODE SER NEGATIVO!';

    /* VERIFICA SE O CAMPO PERCENTUAL DE DESCONTO RECEBE MAIOR DO QUE 100% */
      ELSIF (P_PERCDESC > 100) THEN 
        P_SUCESSO := 'N';
        P_MENSAGEM := 'DESCONTO ULRAPASSOU LIMITE DE 100%';
    ELSE 
        P_SUCESSO := 'S';
    END IF;
  
        P_SUCESSO := 'S';
  
END ;
```

Comment: Seria mais simples uma check constraint https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Vou dar uma lida  nessa documentação.

Comment: Bom dia, poderia me dizer qual o erro nessa verificação para me trazer o erro : SQL Error [2293] [23000]: ORA-02293: cannot validate (TESTE.CK_PERCDESC) - check constraint violated  ` ALTER TABLE TGFITE
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PERCDESC
CHECK ( PERCDESC BETWEEN 0 AND 100);`

Comment: Justamente você tem PERCDESC  que não obedece a regra , faça   ALTER TABLE TGFITE ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PERCDESC CHECK ( PERCDESC BETWEEN 0 AND 100) 
  ENABLE NOVALIDATE; que o Oracle vai aceitar a constraint mas só dará erro em algum update , o melhor seria "acertar" a base se possível.

Comment: Entendi. Então, o problema é que o software é de terceiro e acionamos a empresa e ela disse que é normal isso dai e portanto não será ajustado. Por isso tentei fazer a procedure a cima ou esse método que instruiu.

Comment: A constraint deu certo da forma que me orientou, Motta, muito obrigado. Testei no insert de um item e como vem com o valor 0,00 então acusa a violão por se tratar de um update no campo.